# Any way to prevent k8s pod eviction?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a set of daemons I need to run, generally, they do not consume much memory or CPU and I have their `limits` to `cpu: 150m` and `memory: 150m`.

Occasionally they will spike to quite a bit higher than this and this seems to be causing evictions and unstable node.

It is critical that the daemons remain running 24/7, even if they are throttled by CPU and/or memory when they spike. Is it possible to prevent their eviction and to cap their resources?

As I understand the CPU usage is throttled but over memory use results in an OOM eviction, is there any way to prevent this eviction?

Comment: If they are critical and must keep running why don't you set the limits accordingly? It looks like those limits are working as they should in your case.

Comment: I am interrogating that aspect now to determine the optimal settings

Comment: If you are not forced to set the limits by resource quotas you can leave them unbounded or set them high to get a better idea of what the actual limits should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to track the resources consumption trends with something like Prometheus + Grafana to check what sort of spikes you expect from your DaemonSets.

Then you can allocate more resources to these pods or remove this config (which, by default, will leave them in `unbounded` mode). But, of course, you don't want to risk a full node / host crash so you can consider tweaking your `eviction threshold`:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#eviction-thresholds

More details:
https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/admin/limitrange/

Answer (score 6):

As of 1.11, you can set [pod priorities](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/).

1. create priority class

> ```
> apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1
> kind: PriorityClass
> metadata:
>   name: high-priority
> value: 1000000
> globalDefault: false
> description: "This priority class should be used for XYZ service pods only."
> ```

2. set priority in pod

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: nginx
>   labels:
>     env: test
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - name: nginx
>     image: nginx
>     imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
>   priorityClassName: high-priority
> ```